# The use of '__user' in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel

For example,
`int setup_sigcontext(struct sigcontext __user *sc, struct pt_regs *regs)`,it makes sense to me.
But I can't understand something like this,`SYSCALL_DEFINE3(sigaltstack, const stack_t __user *, uss,stack_t __user *, uoss, struct pt_regs *, regs)`.Why there's a ',' between 'const stack_t __user*' and 'uss'.Through the body of this function, I can conclude that 'const stack_t __user' modefy 'uss'.I've learned that '__user' is a macro

Comment: `__user` macro indicates these context pointers are on the userspace stack. Macro is defined in `compiler_types.h` here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.7/source/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L22
Not sure about that comma.

Answer (score 0):

SYSCALL_DEFINE3 is a macro for a syscall with 3 arguments.  It's arguments are described here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L101

The first is the name of the syscall, this is followed by 3 pairs of (type, name), which are the type and name of each argument.  This allows the compiler to meet the calling conventions for a syscall on the various architectures where Linux can run.